# Installing Snippits fails

Tags: 10.04, ruby

I am trying to install [snippits](http://snippits.rubyforge.org/), but it fails with the error message

```
ERROR:  Error installing snippits:
    hoe requires RubyGems version >= 1.4
```

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have to install RubyGems to:

```
sudo aptitude install rubygems
```

(or search in synaptic for rubygems)

Ok, just recognized there is no RubyGems > 1.3.7 in the Ubuntu repository (Debian actually has a 1.6 in sid...). So you have to install it from their [website](http://rubygems.org/pages/download).

Comment: It's the installing from the source. apptitude and old packages is the problem.